# jQuery Validation not validating on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
$('div.nextStepBilling').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "newCardDiv") {
        $('form#myForm').validate({
            rules: {
                cardHolder: "required",
                cardNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 15,
                    maxlength: 16
                },
                CVV: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 4
                }
            },
            messages: {
                cardHolder: "Card holder name is required",
                cardNumber: {
                    required: "Credit card number is required",
                    minlength: "Credit card must be at least 15 digits long",
                    maxlength: "Credit card must be at most 16 digits long"
                },
                CVV: {
                    required: "CVV (security code) is required",
                    minlength: "CVV must be at least 3 digits long",
                    maxlength: "CVV must be at most 4 digits long"
                }
            }
        });
        if ($('form#myForm').valid()) {
            alert("valid");
        } else {
            alert("invalid");
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on the proper `div.nextStepBilling`it always alerts valid, even if there is nothing in those inputs.

I don't get any errors in the console and I can get jquery validate to work using `$('form#myForm').validate().element("#cardHolder");` I have the latest jquery and jquery validate packages included (in proper order) on the page. Can anyone see anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: You should also show the relevant HTML markup so we can know more about this button.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
$('div.nextStepBilling').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "newCardDiv") {
        $('form#myForm').validate({
            // rules & options
            ...
```

Because `.validate()` is only the *initialization* method of the plugin, it is ***not*** the *testing* method.  The `.validate()` method only gets called *once* on DOM ready to initialize the plugin with your rules & options.  All subsequent calls are ignored.

You would use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) to programmatically trigger a validation test on demand.

Your code should look more like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form#myForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // rules & options
    });

    $('div.nextStepBilling').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "newCardDiv") {
            $('form#myForm').valid(); // triggers a test on the form
            ...
```

**Simple DEMOS**:  http://jsfiddle.net/zSq94/ and http://jsfiddle.net/zSq94/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do however have the `.valid();` in an if statement right underneath the initialization. The problem is that my form requires multiple validation rules so I need to initialize it only when that button is clicked as other buttons will have different validation rules.

Comment: @hjavaher, it does not matter, your problem is still being caused by not initializing the plugin on DOM ready; and you cannot change rules by dynamically calling `.validate()` again... it's always ignored on all subsequent calls.  There are other methods like `rules('add')` and `rules('remove')` that are used for changing rules after the initialization.  If you want more help, please improve your question by including the markup and a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. I will try that and report back. Thanks